# PDO rollback if another block of code fails

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to rollBack a PDO transaction based on the results of another block of code. This works great if the DB insert fails but if the "other stuff" throws an exception, it's not rolling back the commit. What am I doing wrong?

PHP version 5.4, database is MS SQL

```
<?php
    try {   
        $dbh = new PDO($dataSource);
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table
                    (field1, field2, etc)
                VALUES
                    (:field1, :field2, :etc)"
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':field1', $data["field1"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':field2', $data["field2"]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':etc', $data["etc"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $dbh->commit();

        //do some other stuff which can throw an Exception
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //make sure we have something to roll back
        try { $dbh->rollBack(); } catch (Exception $e2) {}
        $log->logFatal("Error: controller.inc.php: " . $e->getMessage());
    }   
?>
```

Comment: You can't `commit()` if you plan to `rollBack()` on any future error after committing. You would need to move your `commit()` to occur after the other stuff.

Comment: Thanks! A bit rusty with SQL. Is it typical then to have no real way of catching an error with commit() itself? Because I can't undo the other code (sending an email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `commit()` effectively completes the open transaction begun earlier by `beginTransaction()`, so following the call to `commit()` there is no database action remaining to `rollBack()`.

If you have other code you want to run following a successful commit, you can check its return value in an `if()` block.  [`PDO::commit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) will return `FALSE` if the commit action itself fails, so you can prevent your mail action when it does by throwing another exception.

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO($dataSource);
  $dbh->beginTransaction();
  // etc...
  // etc...

  // Attempt to commit, and do other actions if successful
  if ($pdo->commit()) {
    // Do other actions
    // mail, etc...
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise, throw another exception which your catch {} will handle
    throw new Exception('Transaction was not committed');
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Docs are unclear on whether rollBack() will throw an error on failure
  // or just return false. It is documented to throw an exception if 
  // no transaction is actually active.
  try { $pdo->rollBack(); } catch (Exception $e2) {}
    // Log your error, either a normal PDO error, or failed commit()...
    $log->logFatal("Error: controller.inc.php: " . $e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Ooh I like this even better than the solution I had after your last comment. Thanks!